# Finding modulus of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, triangle-inequality

The  question is as follows:

if $|a|=|b|=|c|=|b+c-a|=1$ where $a$,$b$,$c$  are distinct complex numbers , find $|b+c|$.

**My attempt:** By observation that $b=i$, $c=-i$, $a=1$ satisfy the following conditions

thus $|b+c| =|i-i|=0$

I realise that this is not a generalised method. Is there a better metod to solve this problem?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are infinitely many solutions that satisfy that conditions.

Some of these will be in the form $b=-c$ and $|a|=1, a\in\Bbb C$.  In this case, $|b+c|=0$ as you have discovered.

However, many more can be found.  Define \begin{align}
a&=\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha\\
b&=\cos\beta+i\sin\beta\\
c&=\cos\gamma+i\sin\gamma
\end{align}
In order to satisfy $|b+c-a|=1$, we can have any set of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ such that $$\sqrt{(\cos\beta+\cos\gamma-\cos\alpha)^2+(\sin\beta+\sin\gamma-\sin\alpha)^2}=1.$$
Sure, it may be possible to parameterize your solution, but I suspect that there is more to the problem that has been left out.  This is probably as far as we can go.